# linear to log slider value for filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have set a filter section for my drum pads and it works fine except for the values it represents i would like to convert the values from linear to log the code is as follows

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="sectionEffects">

            <div id="Effect1">
            <title> Effect 1 </title>
            <p>
            Filter on: <input class="slider" type="checkbox" checked="false" oninput="biquadFilter.togglebiquadFilter(this);"/>
            </p>
            <p>
            Frequency: <input type="range" min="0" max="40" step="1" value="20000" onChange="" id="filter"/>
            </p>
            <p class="note">Current value: <span id="currentValue">0</span></p>

            </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var selectedPad = "";
var padCutoffs = [];


padCutoffs["Kick"] = 20000;
padCutoffs["Snare"] = 20000;
padCutoffs["Tom"] = 20000;
padCutoffs["Crash"] = 20000;
padCutoffs["Roll"] = 20000;
padCutoffs["Hi-Hat"] = 20000;

$('#filter').on("change mousemove", function() {
          padCutoffs[selectedPad] = $(this).val()* 500; //look up linear to log
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a lookup table?  You can do this two ways:

1. Use the math functions - Math.log2(x) and Math.pow(2, x) - to convert between actual data.
2. Instead of pure numbers, just use the filter.detune AudioParam (after setting filter.frequency to a known number).  For example, for a 5-octave filter sweep, set filter.frequency.value=0, then vary detune from a min of 0 to a max of 1200*5.  (Detune is in cents, 1200 cents per octave.)

Answer (score 0):

What I could think of was creating an exponential regression from the data (I used desmos) and I got y = 1058500*e^(9.0015)x-131640
you could approximate e to 2.71828